# Zoom in a part of the window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zooming

I am loading some dynamic content on my web page in a particular `div`. This content will be scaled to be shown entirely in the `div`, and I want to allow the users to zoom in this `div`. Since this is for the mobile version of the page, I'm afraid it would be too small. The rest of the screen should remain unchanged.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="some_static_part"></div>
   <div id="dynamic_part"></div>
   <div id="some_other_static_part"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#some_static_part{
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
}

#dynamic_part{
  width:50%;
  height:75%;
}

#some_other_static_part{
  width:50%;
  height:75%;
}
```

Comment: on mobiles by default you get a zoom effect.

Comment: But is it possible to zoom only in this part by pinching?

Comment: is it an image or something??

Comment: It's some kind of frame, with some HTML

Answer (score 0):

This is something which will help you. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SefxW/)

```
<div id="sampleDiv" style="width: 100px; background-color: Gray;">
            Zoom Me
        </div>
```

**EDIT :** 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SefxW/4/)

```
     <div id="sampleDiv" ondblclick="sampleDiv.style.zoom='300%'" onclick="sampleDiv.style.zoom='100%'" style="width: 100px; background-color: Gray;">
            Zoom
</div>
```

On Double click:300% zoom 
On single click: return to default.

Comment: Thanks but none of the fiddles work for me (on Firefox). Before posting this question, I've read about the "zoom" property and saw this was something to avoid, as it was an old IE tag, and it was better to use the CSS "transform" property. However, this is not what I want, all I want is allow the users to scroll and pinch in the frame without having any effect on the rest of the page.

Comment: oh.. Probably you can use an iframe to catch your dynamic contents in a div. i am unsure about it.